# Store Type in field/variable

Tags: c#, static, field

How can I store a Type in a static field, so that I can do something like this (note: just an example, in pseudocode)?:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static Type Writer;

    public static void SetWriter(Type @new)
    {
        Writer = @new;
    }

    public static void Write(string str)
    {
        Writer.Write(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ? not in code but as an abstract idea ?

Comment: I'm trying to store a Type in any kind of variable, but a Type in itself isn't a statement, so it doesn't work...

Comment: Can't you use an instance of some type, instead of `Type`? Maybe something like `TextWriter`?

Comment: @Jwosty Yes, but *why* do you want to do that? What's the underlying reason?

Comment: Indeed svick; I'm thinking that the behaviour he wants might also be better implemented with Generics; rather then holding types; just have a helper class that works on types. Generics or some interface design anyway.

Comment: Alright, changed the post to answer your questions

Comment: You have totally changed the question, to the point where answers you have now are meaningless.  I would suggest undoing the edits to this question and using the text you have now to create a new question.

Answer (score 37):

Very simple:

```
Type variableName = typeof(SomeTypeName);
```

or

```
Type variableName = someObject.GetType();
```

Not sure this will help with what you actually want to do, though.  See the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Except for the fact that `new` is a keyword, your code to store the type should work fine.

However, your code

```
Writer.Write(str);
```

is meaningless.

The class `Type` does not have a method `Write(string)`.

It feels like what you are after is an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

```
public interface IWriter
{
    public Write(string text);
}

public class Logger
{
    public static IWriter Writer;

    public static void SetWriter(IWriter newWriter)
    {
        Writer = newWriter;
    }

    public static void Write(string str)
    {
        Writer.Write(str);
    }
}
```

That way, you would pass any class that implements `IWriter` into `SetWriter`, e.g.

```
public class MyWriter : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string text)
    {
        // Do something to "write" text
    }
}

Logger.SetWriter(new MyWriter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that example code makes no sense, but why not simply use a common interface?  For example, all (I think all at least) of the text writing types in the `System.IO` namespace inherit from the abstract class `TextWriter`, so...

For example:

```
public class Logger
{
    public Logger(TextWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    private TextWriter _writer;    

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        _writer.Write(text);
    }
}
```

Now, is it a good idea to make the writer public and rely on users of your code to make sure it is always valid? Probably not, but that's more a design consideration.  Also, your java style setter is A) atypical for C# which has nice syntactical support for properties, and B) useless as the backing field is public anyway.